# Synonym request: angular-google-maps

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request, synonym-request

I am a maintainer on Angular Google Maps. Yesterday, I broke 1.5k reputation, and was finally able to create a tag, [agm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm)

There are two older tags -- [agm-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm-map) and [agm-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm-core). [agm-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm-map) is a Component of our library. [agm-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm-core), is one of the three deliverables we currently provide. They are based on the same codebase, and usage questions should really be part of the library.

My request is to merge these two tags into [agm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm) which will be the master tag for the library. We will also add this tag into our GitHub readme page.

Additionally, there is an existing [angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps) tag, which is for an AngularJS library. The tag's wiki itself says that the library is '...No longer actively maintained'. I request that [angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps) tag is renamed to [angularjs-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-google-maps), and a new [angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps) tag is created as a synonym for [agm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm). Alternatively, if you think it's more descriptive, [angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps) can be the parent tag, and [agm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm) a synonym.

Edit: I just noticed that there is also [angular2-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-google-maps) tag, with 37 questions. It should also be marked as a synonym, but ***not*** the main tag, as we don't call our library angular2-google-maps

Edit2: So apparently there is an anti TLA rule, so the final request is to make the main tag [angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps), change the description/wiki of [angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps), and make [agm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm) [agm-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm-core) [agm-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agm-maps) [angular2-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-google-maps) synonyms of [angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps)

Comment: TLAs are not appropriate, unless it has [php] chops.

Comment: I don't know SO convention, but if so, I offered an alternative in the last sentence

Comment: [tag:agm-core] and [tag:agm-map] are tiny tags, and shouldn't be a problem. However, it appears as though around half of the [tag:angular-google-maps] questions are *actually* using angular, not angularjs - despite the wiki ([A very naive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps%2b-angularjs?tab=active&page=5&pagesize=15)). That'll be a bit trickier to untangle. Also agree with Hans that [tag:agm] isn't the most descriptive - so we'll need to sort out what to do with the big tag, first

Comment: Good catch, @Rob. Since [tag:angular-google-maps] only 205 questions, I guess we can pretty easily go down the list of all questions and migrate them to [tag:angularjs-google-maps] if need be. It is fairly trivial to triage most of them, based on other tags in the question.

Comment: Correction: 478 questions tagged. Also, there is a somewhat sharp cutoff point of first half of 2017, before which all questions are angularjs, and after, [tag:angular]